# ¿Por que no se muestran todos los datos almacenados?

Tags: c++, array, estructuras

estoy haciendo un programa con estructuras en c++, al amacenar los datos dentro de la variable "alumnno x[4]" todo va perfectamente, el problema es al querer mostrar los datos de los 4 alumnos, porque solo se muestran los datos del primer alumno.
Este es mi codigo:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct direccion{
    
    char calle[50];
    int numero;
    char colonia[50];
    
    
};

struct alumno{
    
    char nombre[50];
    
     direccion direc;
    
    int calif[3];
};


int main(){
    
    int a =4;
    alumno x[a];
    
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        
        cout<<"Digita el nombre: "<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].nombre;
        cout<<"Digita el calle: "<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].direc.calle;
        cout<<"Digita el numero de casa: "<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].direc.numero;
        cout<<"Digita la colonia: "<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].direc.colonia;
        
        cout<<"\n";
        
        for(int g=0; g<3; g++){
            
            cout<<"Calificacion: "<<g+1<<endl;
            cin>>x[i].calif[g];
        }
        
        cout<<"\n";
        
    }
    
    system("cls");
    
    for (int c=0; c<4; c++){
        
        cout<<"Nombre: "<<x[c].nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"Calle: "<<x[c].direc.calle<<endl;
        cout<<"Numero: "<<x[c].direc.numero<<endl;
        cout<<"Coloinia: "<<x[c].direc.colonia<<endl;
        
    getch();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Ya he hecho programas similares y han funcionado bien, por lo que no logro entender donde esta mi error.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Saludos. Después del **getch();** tienes un **return 0;**; este **return** lo tienes dentro del **for**, quitalo de ahí y que no sea parte del **for**.

Comment: Prueba `constexpr int a = 4` para definir el tamaño de la formación de alumnos.

Answer (score 1):

trata de identar mejor tu codigo, colocaste el return 0 y el getch() dentro del ciclo for, y el return 0 hace que finalice el programa, baja esas dos lineas de codigo hasta antes de la ultima llave.

En lugar de esto:

```
    for (int c=0; c<4; c++){
        
        cout<<"Nombre: "<<x[c].nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"Calle: "<<x[c].direc.calle<<endl;
        cout<<"Numero: "<<x[c].direc.numero<<endl;
        cout<<"Coloinia: "<<x[c].direc.colonia<<endl;
        
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Debería tener la llave de cierre del `for` antes del `getch()`:

```
for (int c=0; c<4; c++){
    
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<x[c].nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Calle: "<<x[c].direc.calle<<endl;
    cout<<"Numero: "<<x[c].direc.numero<<endl;
    cout<<"Coloinia: "<<x[c].direc.colonia<<endl;
}    

getch();
return 0;
```

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.